# Single quotes with in javascript double quote

Tags: javascript

I have an issue in javascript that i need to have the code like this.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="from_date"  name="from_date" data-inputmask="'alias': 'dd/mm/yyyy'" data-mask>
```

And  the code inside my javascript is

```
strinner="<legend>Attachment "+numrows+" </legend><div class='row'> <div class='col-md-4'><div class='form-group'><input type='text' id='attachment_caption"+numrows+"' name='attachment_caption"+numrows+"' placeholder='Attachment caption'  class='form-control'/></div> </div><div class='col-md-3'><div class='form-group'><input type='file' id='document"+numrows+"' name='document"+numrows+"' onclick='disableurl("+numrows+")' /></div></div><div class='col-md-1'><label for=''></label><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-4/512/close-128.png' title='Click to remove File'  id='clear_multiple"+numrows+"' height='18px'  style='cursor:pointer' onclick='remove("+numrows+")'/></div><div class='col-md-4'><div class='form-group'><input type='text'  id='url"+numrows+"' name='url"+numrows+"' placeholder='Attachment URL' onkeyup='disablefile("+numrows+")'   class='form-control'/></div></div></div><div class='row'><div class='col-md-4'><div class='form-group'><label>From Date:</label><div class='input-group'><div class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-calendar'></i></div>**<input type='text' class='form-control' id='from_date1'  name='from_date1'  data-inputmask='alias:dd/mm/yyyy' data-mask>**</div></div></div></div>";
```

The problem is in field with id from_date in strinner.I need

```
 data-inputmask="'alias': 'dd/mm/yyyy'"
```

Help me please

Comment: One could hardly imagine a better example of why not to build complex HTML as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape `"` using [escape notaion `\"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation).

```
strinner = ".... data-inputmask=\"'alias': 'dd/mm/yyyy'\" .......";
```

Comment: thanks.it worked.But I think this will solve my real problem.But didn't;-(

Comment: @VimalS :  what you mean by real problem ?

Comment: @ Pranav C Balan-It's apart of a project.The date mask of the adminLte is not working when i am dynamically creating these fields.

Comment: @VimalS maybe it doesn't care about dynamic elements... either you need to reinitialize it after dynamic element added.... which plugin is using for masking?

Comment: @ Pranav C Balan-input mask plugin in AdminLte-

Comment: @VimalS :  after element is dynamically added .. try `Inputmask().mask(document.querySelectorAll("input"));`

Comment: @ Pranav C Balan-no pranav it doesn't work..thankyou for your help

Comment: @VimalS :  for make it work you need to share the exact mask plugin info :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132896/discussion-between-vimal-s-and-pranav-c-balan).